# File permissions for multi-user process

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

I want to give a bunch of users (U1, U2,...,Un) on the same Linux server each a directory where they can read and write (D1, D2,..., Dn).

So Ui should be able to read/write to directory Di, but Ui should not be able to read or write to directory Dj (where i != j)

Then I want to have a script S that reads from each directory Di.

Is there a way to set this up with chown, chmod, and adding users to different groups and so on?

Comment: who runs script S?  root? admin?

Comment: @jimmcnamara: A custom user/group could be setup to run script S, but it could be run as root if necessary.  Script S needs to read from every directory (D1, D2,..., Dn).

Comment: @user1131467 I find your level of abstraction here a bit confusing. Could you elaborate or give a concrete example?

Comment: @Ahrotahntee: Which abstraction are you finding confusing?  What do you not understand exactly?

Comment: (where i != j) < This is adding a new condition of access not previously mentioned, or reiterating that Di != Dj?

Comment: @Ahrotahntee:  For example, user U3 should only be able to access directory D3 (his own directory), and should not be able to access directory D1, D2, D4, D5, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could `chmod 700 eachDirectory` making the directories read/write/exec for only the owner of the directory and root. You could then run the script as root.

To run the script as a user other than root, you could give that user access using FACLs.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 750` will meet all your requirements

Comment: This is rwxr-x--- meaning every member of the whole group can get into the directory.